# Building a TimePickerDialog method

Tags: android, methods, datetimepicker

I got 4 EditText views with different variables for each of them. I want to call a TimePickerDialog when clicking on each one of the EditText views and pass the relevant parameters each time, so I was trying to build a method for this instead of writing the whole code 4 times:

```
public TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog(Context context, final EditText editText, int hour, int minute){
    TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            hour = selectedHour; // This 2 lines are my problem
            minute = selectedMinute; // This 2 lines are my problem
            editText.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
            editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }, hour, minute, true);

    timePicker.setTitle(R.string.select_time);
    timePicker.show();

    return timePicker;
```

than for each EditText's onClick i call the method with the relevant parameters:

```
timePickerDialog(getActivity(), mEditText, mHour, mMinute);
```

My problem is on this 2 lines:

```
hour = selectedHour; 
minute = selectedMinute;
```

I get the error:

```
Variable 'hour/minute' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final
```

While changing them to final gives me this error:

```
Cannot assign a value to final variable
```

Any suggestions to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the two messages that you get:

> Variable 'hour/minute' is accessed from within inner class, needs to
>   be declared final

Any variable in Java that is accessed from an anonymous inner class has to be declared as final.

> Cannot assign a value to final variable

You can only assign a value to a variable only once; the time you instantiate it. You try to re-assign a value therefore you will get an error message.

**Workaround**: There are many ways to overcome this let me suggest the simpler one. You remove the two int arguments from `timePickerDialog()`, have them set from outside your inner class as `final Integer[] hourMinute = new Integer[1];` and set their values from within your inner class like hourMinute[0]=selectedHour; and `hourMinute[0]=selectedMinute`.